# How to access constant in another file inside an Angular template

Tags: angular, typescript

In a dedicated `permissions.model.ts`, I'm listing a list of permissions(that can be matched to some information on my JWT).

Basically, looks like this:

```
export const Permissions = {
  System: {
    SomeSettings: {
      Update: "permissions.some-string",
    },
    SomeOtherSettings: {
      Update: "permissions.some-other-string",
    },
    AnySettings: {
      Update: "permissions.some-other-other-string",
    },
  },
  UserManagement: {
    Users: {
      Abc: "permissions.some-other-other-other-other-string",
      Def: "permissions.some-other-other-other-other-other-string",
    },
  },
};
```

In my component, I need to access it:

```
<div *ngIf="Permissions.System.SomeSettings| hasPermission | async">
   <!-- ...-->
</div>
```

But angular is not happy because it doesn't know where to gets `Permissions` from. I tried to import in the matching `.ts` file, but it doesn't help.

Can this be done? Without creating a property in the ViewModel that returns the matching property of the constant?

Comment: Yes I know, but I will to do this in 3/4 of my components, so I'm interested in finding a way that doesn't require me to wrap it on each component(in which case I would probably make a service that provide those constants).

Comment: You may create a component superclass that has the constants needed in templates. This way you will avoid the necessity to declare properties on each component manually.